# RSpec stubbing a mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, actionmailer

I have a `UserMailDispatcher` class whose job it is to delver mail via `ActiveMailer` based on certain criteria.

I'm trying to test it using RSpec but am coming up short. I would like to somehow stub a test mailer and see if the class properly delivers it. Here's what I have so far:

All my mailers inherit from ApplicationMailer:

application_mailer.rb

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  append_view_path Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'mailers')
end
```

user_mail_dispatcher_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe UserMailDispatcher do 
  class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer 
    def test_mail
      mail
    end
  end

  it "mails stuff" do
    ???
  end
end
```

I want to test that the dispatcher can properly queue/deliver mail. However, I cannot seem to call `UserMailer.test_mail.deliver_now`. I get `missing template 'user_mailer/test_mail'` I tried adding `type: :view` to the spec and using `stub_template 'user_mailer/test_mail.html.erb'`, but I get the same error.

I do have a `UserMailer` defined but I don't want to test any of its methods here since those are more likely to change.

Any ideas on how to best handle this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to stub it, or do you simply want to know that mail was sent? Also, is there some reason you can't implemented the required template?  Mailer actions usually have an associated template.

Comment: I simply want to know all of the required mail was sent. I like that idea of just implementing the test template, and it works (thanks!!), but it seems like a really hacky solution to this. I feel like a better way would be to stub the template somehow.

Comment: Would you ever use the `test_mail` action in production?

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue as well when I was testing using a DummyMailer and to get around it I just asked the mail method to return plain text like this:

```
mail do |format|
  format.text { render plain: "Hello World!" }
end
```

Here is the [documentation for it](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActionMailer%2FBase%3Amail), scroll down a little bit to find the right section.

Answer (score 0):

Add the required template and test without stubbing by using `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries`.  Here's an example (in minitest) from the guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers).

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  test "invite" do
    # Send the email, then test that it got queued
    email = UserMailer.create_invite('me@example.com',
                                     'friend@example.com', Time.now).deliver_now
    assert_not ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?

    # Test the body of the sent email contains what we expect it to
    assert_equal ['me@example.com'], email.from
    assert_equal ['friend@example.com'], email.to
    assert_equal 'You have been invited by me@example.com', email.subject
    assert_equal read_fixture('invite').join, email.body.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: I get what you're doing here, but what I'm trying to do is decouple the UserMailDispatcher from any actual UserMailer methods. I don't want to call an actual method and render an actual template (I can do the actual template specs in the UserMailer test), I just want to stub them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way how to test that mailer is called with right arguments.

```
it 'sends email' do
  delivery = double
  expect(delivery).to receive(:deliver_now).with(no_args)

  expect(UserMailer).to receive(:test_mail)
    .with('my_arguments')
    .and_return(delivery)

  UserMailDispatcher.my_function
end
```